How to recover an App Clip link that was broken due to Bad HTTP Status?
I have an app with app-clip in the app-store, and due to an update in the server, the aasa file was corrupted.
the app-clip kept working, until we released a new version - and then when trying to open the app-clip from the QR code - it failed saying: "App Clip is unavailable".
in appstoreconnect - both DEBUG STATUS and CACHE STATUS of our BUILD DOMAIN was: "Bad HTTP Response"
after the issue was fixed in the server - DEBUG STATUS was changed to "Validated"
(as shown in the picture)
but still the app-clip didn't work from QR scanning, although it did work from apple's direct link -
https://appclip.apple.com/id?p=
So, my questions are -

Do I need to just wait until for the cache to refresh?

how often it's getting refreshed?

would it help if I upload a new version?




I'm having exactly the same situation, mine was due to the server serving the apple-app-site-association file being down for a day or two.
Did you manage to fix the issue?
Do we just have to wait a few hours that apple refreshes its cache?

Hi @pot2mayo! I hope you managed... in my case - I uploaded a new version in order to fix it.
would be grateful if you upvote, cause somebody really likes to down-vote on my questions...

I waited almost 2 days for it to refresh the status but it didn't happen.
At the end (after verifying again the website has the correct aasa file), I uploaded a new version - and the domain status was updated.
it's weird but app-clip now works. I guess the domain app-clip association is implemented in the app in such a way that if you upload it when the web is corrupted than this version is screwed.
